# Twitch.tv Api C# Get Streams

Tags: javascript, c#, json, twitch

I want to create a Twitch.tv app for desktop Pc. I have read that Twitch api use Json for the streams.
Can someone please explain me how I get the streams into a list? I plan to use C# get the list into a listbox but im stuck and cant continue because I dont know how to get what is available

Another way I was thinking is using Javascript but same problem can someone help me?

Comment: Please explain what did you tried and what type of problem you face.

Comment: I was watching this post https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v2_resources/streams.md#get-streamschannel. I dont know where to start :|

Comment: https://github.com/gibletto/twitch.net

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://$SITEURL$/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://$SITEURL$/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The github shows how you can get stream from twitch. First you send a request like shown on github "curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v2+json' -X GET https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/test_channel" then you will get a JSON file (that contains all the information you need) as a response, you the read the file and use it in your application

Comment: Ok I read the file and then add each json object into a listbox. How am I going to select a specific stream?

Comment: in a JSON file you have the URL: for example :"url": http://www.twitch.tv/test_channel",  to view the stream simply access that link